# Pull specific XML Data using HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm actually having issues writing a loop in the correct location. I've been testing for a few days, but I can't figure out why it won't loop where I want it.

I'm taking the exported XML from MSDN and trying to organize it properly.

My XML Looks like this:

```
<Data>
<Product_Key Name="Access 2010 ">
<Key ID="473" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="10/17/2011">Code1</Key>
<Key ID="473" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/8/2011">Code2</Key>
<Key ID="473" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/7/2011">Code3</Key>
</Product_Key>

<Product_Key Name="Office Professional Plus 2007">
<Key ID="197" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="10/14/2011">Code1</Key>
<Key ID="197" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/23/2011">Code2</Key>
<Key ID="197" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/23/2011">Code3</Key>
<Key ID="197" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/23/2011">Code4</Key>
<Key ID="197" Type="Retail" ClaimedDate="9/23/2011">Code5</Key>
</Product_Key>
</Data>
```

My .js script looks like so:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

and lastly, my HTML looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>


<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("keys.xml");

document.write("<table border='1'>");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Product_Key');
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getAttribute('Name'));
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Key")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure all I need is another loop for the tagname "Key" and I've tried lots of ways for that, but nothing ends up looking correctly.

Maybe I need an if/then statement instead so it tests if the next line is another "Product_Key" or another "Key"???

Currently my output looks like this:

```
Access 2010                          Code1
Office Professional Plus 2007        Code1
```

I'm wanting all the codes displayed like so (but in a table. stackoverflow doesn't support tables in posts, so i had to make due with a modified example):

```
Access 2010                          Code1
                                     Code2
                                     Code3
Office Professional Plus 2007        Code1
                                     Code2
                                     Code3
                                     Code4
                                     Code5
```

Comment: Have you tried to log your variables with `console.log` while processing?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by using console.log. I was under the impression console.log was basically something you wrote to for debugging purposes.

Comment: In other words: What is your expected output, what do you get in reality and what is the difference?

Comment: @heinob I've edited my post due to the restrictions in comments that I can't find a way around. Should help clear up the end result I'm working towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var xmlDoc,
        x,
        y,
        i,
        n;

    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("keys.xml");
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Product_Key');
    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    for( i=0; i<x.length; i+=1 ) {
        y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Key");
        for( n=0; n<y.length; n+=1 ) {
            document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(x[i].getAttribute('Name'));
            document.write("</td><td>");
            document.write( y[n].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
            document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting a strange result when debugging this. 
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
But it looks pretty defined to me..

Comment: Which line produces the error? Are you sure you copied the code 1:1?

Comment: It's the 6th line in your post that is giving the error. "n;" And I'm positive I've copied it 1:1. The only change I made was to <script> at the end.

Comment: O.k. there was a `,` missing behind the `i` in line 5. And I have changed the second `<script>` to `</script>`. Now it should be correct.  See my edit.

Comment: Another error with that while debugging. "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" It's on Line 10.

Comment: see my edit. the line defining `x` was missing. now it is definitely working :-)

Comment: Beautiful! You sir are amazing. I'm not sure how to use stackoverflow very well cause this is my first post, but you deserve more than that green check box, sir.

Comment: Thanks. Two recommendations: a) train JavaScript, b) upvote my answer if you really liked it ;-)